# reading and convert binary data in C++

Tags: c++

I am a new C++ guy, and working on the data collection.I have this code to read and print out data:

```
int main ()
{
  string name;
  ifstream input;
  double vector_length;  
  vector_length = 14;

  //Open the input file
  input.open("data.txt",ios::out | ios::app | ios::binary );

  vector<complex<double> > f(vector_length);  

  for(int i=0; i<vector_length;i++){
      getline (input,name);
      cout  << name << endl;
      istringstream is(name);
      complex<double> c;
      is >> c;
      f[i] = complex<double>(c.real(), c.imag());
      cout << "the complex number is " << c << "\n";
      cout <<"real: " << c.real() << endl;
      cout <<"image:" << c.imag() << endl;

  }
  for(int i=0; i < vector_length;i++){
      cout <<i<<"  "<< f[i]<<endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

---

and the data.txt look like:

```
(16,-144)
(-80,-64)
(-80,16)
(16,48)
(96,95)
(111,-32)
(64,-96)
(64,-16)
(31,-48)
(-96,-48)
(-32,79)
(16,48)
(-80,80)
(-48,128)
```

---

now, I want to do the same way, but get values from binary data `(input.open("data.bin",ios::out | ios::app | ios::binary );)` such as:

```
004038c0  e5 ff 32 00 e1 ff 13 00  00 00 00 00 f9 ff b0 ff  |..2.............| 
004038d0  e8 ff b2 ff de ff f3 ff  c0 ff 06 00 b2 ff 18 00  |................|  
004038e0  41 00 09 00 29 00 bc ff  9f ff f9 ff f8 ff 51 00  |A...).........Q.|
004038f0  0d 00 de ff b1 ff 18 00  c4 ff 26 00 19 00 bd ff  |..........&.....|
00403900  10 00 fe ff 14 00 2e 00  d0 ff 05 00 8f ff fa ff  |................|
00403910  44 00 2a 00 3b 00 c9 ff  ed ff e2 ff f3 ff 21 00  |D.*.;.........!.|
00403920  0e 00 ef ff af ff f8 ff  bf ff f6 ff 0b 00 ce ff  |................|
00403930  03 00 20 00 11 00 0e 00  02 00 6f ff c9 ff c5 ff  |.. .......o.....|
00403940  cf ff f5 ff d5 ff 94 ff  d6 ff a3 ff 25 00 2c 00  |............%.,.|
```

which represent for complex data above.`(16,48)(-80,80)(-48,128)`....But I could not get the data print out.

Comment: Have you tried anything that will read in the binary?  If so, can you please post it so that we can point you in the right direction?

Comment: `f[i] = complex<double>(c.real(), c.imag());` why do you need this?

Comment: What error did you get? What is the code that produced the error? What data did you use, the data shown? Please post an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The `>>` input operator is for text formatted input.

Comment: UkMonkey: I just tried and but it give me nothing or print out this this: `�p����������0P��?��p������@���`�����O���`�0����_p�`0����p���0@�p�p�����p�P������p�0� ���p�0��p ���op��@�������������p���?����@P��`�������� P����� �`@`��@��@����P^C.......................BUT I WOULD LIKE TO HAVE REAL NUMBER.

Comment: Slave: I need to get real and imaginary number from data, that data collected from receivers, then doing filtering.......

Comment: @NateDuong do you understand that line is a convoluted way to say `f[i] = c;` ?

Comment: @NateDuong  So that would be binary data; a good start.  Let's have a look at the code you did to print that, and then we can point out where you're going wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you open `std::ifstream` with flag `ios::binary` only affects how OS handles reading. For example on MS Windows OS converts "\n\r" sequence to "\r" and "ctrl-z" to EOF for text files and not for binary. But that flag would not change `operator>>` to load binary data. You have to use `std::ifstream::read()` method to read binary data into memory:

```
double real = 0, imag = 0;
input.read( reinterpret_cast<char *>( &real ), sizeof( real ) );
input.read( reinterpret_cast<char *>( &imag ), sizeof( imag ) );
complex<double> c( real, imag );
```

Comment: Given that the OP hasn't posted any relevant code, and the only clue so far is that printing the data isn't working, I don't think you can assume that the file reading is the fault at all yet.

Comment: @UKMonkey my understanding that OP uses the same code, just added `ios::binary` flag to `std::ifstream`

Comment: but then cout<< wouldn't be printing out binary data; it would be just printing out rubbish

Comment: Slava: it kind of read only 1st value of the data (for example: (16,-144) data above). So, If I want to print all of the data, what should be the best? Thank you.

Comment: @Slava it kind of read only 1st value of the data (for example: (16,-144) data above). So, If I want to print all of the data, what should be the best? Thank you.

Comment: @NateDuong to print data you do not need to change anything, unless you need to output binary data.

Comment: @Slava I am sorry this is first practice, I can not relate to the binary data (for example: 00403940  cf ff f5 ff d5 ff 94 ff  d6 ff a3 ff 25 00 2c 00  |............%.,.|) . how can I put it into the code?

Comment: @NateDuong I do not quite understand your question, if you mean how you read binary data into variables, I've already shown that in my answer.

Comment: @slava double real = 0, imag = 0; will give us the complex value(0,0), for the output. what about binary data which i provided above? how I can convert as the way you shown me?

Comment: @NateDuong did you read the answer? do you see there are 2 lines of code after I initialize double values?

Comment: @slava also I have a Matlab code to read binary data:                                fid=fopen('data.bin');       fseek(fid,4 * nstart,'bof');                                     y = fread(fid,[2,nsamps],'short');      fclose(fid);                                            x = complex(y(1,:),y(2,:)); Do you have any ideal to convert it into C++?

Comment: @NateDuong for `FILE *` there are `fread/fwrite` functions that do basically the same.